# get attribute from class not working php 7

Tags: php, variables, reference, global-variables, php-7

I have `$this->table` as a global variable and an object inside of it, where foo is a table field name.

example.

```
$this->table = t_module::__set_state(array('foo'=>"bar"))
```

calling another function I know that `$quux['field']` contains `foo`, so I can get the value from the array inside `$this->table`.

```
$baz = $this->table->$quux['field']
```

In php 5.6 I get the correct value, `'bar'`. But trying this in php 7 I get NULL as returning value. I need to get `'bar'` in php 7.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the [migration guide for PHP 7](http://php.net/migration70.incompatible) you should see that one of the Backwards incompatible changes listed there is [the handling of indirect variables, properties, and methods](http://php.net/migration70.incompatible#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling.indirect) which simply put, means that in PHP 7 everything is read from *left-to-right*.

This means in the expression `$baz = $this->table->$quux['field']` the expression`$this->table->$quux` will be evaluated **first** to whatever its value is and *then* PHP will attempt to find the key `['field']` on *that* expression.

Meaning that PHP 5 reads this as

```
$baz = $this->table->{$quux['field']}
```

But PHP 7 reads it as

```
$baz = ($this->table->$quux)['field']
```

To maintain backwards compatibility you can use the braces to force the expression to be evaluated the same in both PHP 5 and PHP 7 like this...

```
$baz = $this->table->{$quux['field']}
```

Here's an [example in 3v4l](https://3v4l.org/lJ1Pd) demonstrating it works the same in both PHP 5 and PHP 7.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Unfortunately it is not easy to find these documents in PHP documentation. specially when you are directly migrating from PHP5 to PHP8

Answer (score 0):

Changes from PHP5 to PHP7

```
`Expression: $foo->$bar['baz']  PHP 5: $foo->{$bar['baz']} PHP7: ($foo->$bar)['baz']`
```

so you have to change it like:

`$baz = $this->table->{$quux['field']}`